# How to concatenate string with a variable in the variable in js

Tags: javascript

I want to have the variable, which name will be contacted var and string

```
function(name){
  var name + "string" = ...
}
```

Comment: So you want to use the concatenated string as the *variable name*? Don't do that. Use an array or object instead.

Comment: plenty of dupes out there if I can find one. Bracket notation is what you need.

Comment: ``${ variable name } some text for concat`` - es6 or `variable name + "some text for concat"` - es5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use bracket notation and insert variables inside an object.

Something like this:

```
var createName = function(name, container){
  container[name + "String"] = 'He is Beautiful, I love him. <3';
  return container;
}
```

If you call

```
createName('Rodmentou', names);
console.log(names[RodmentouString]);
```

You will receive, as output:

> He is Beautiful, I love him. <3

Answer (score -2):

Your question is not clear and does not make sense to programmer. Anyway, to concatenate a string with another string you can use `concat` function.

```
var str1 = "Hello ";
var str2 = "world!";
var res = str1.concat(str2); // 'Helloworld'
 or
var res = str1.concat('world'); // 'Helloworld'
```

or you can use '+' operator :

```
 var str1 = "Hello ";
    var str2 = "world!";
   var str = str1 + str2; // 'Helloworld'
   var str = 'Hello'+'world'; // 'Helloworld'
```

Comment: http://codepaste.net/czmcvn